# "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type" Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am getting the following error at runtime while trying to create a bluetooth multiplayer game:

```
fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

I have looked at other answers to people who have had similar problems and I get the idea that it is something to do with NSDictionary. Before marking as a duplicate, know that I have tried the suggestions on the other questions without any luck. I cannot see anything wrong with it, and neither does the compiler apparently! Here is where I have used the NSDicationary.

```
func peerChangedStateWithNotification(notification:NSNotification){
    let userInfo = NSDictionary(dictionary: notification.userInfo!)

    let state = userInfo.objectForKey("state") as Int

    if state != MCSessionState.Connecting.toRaw(){
        self.navigationItem.title = "Connected"
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've identified the right area of code that is crashing? I see no use of arrays in that code.